# Predator-Prey Model

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, biology

Can anyone explain the biological interpretation on the right hand side of these equations please?

$$ \begin{array}{r c l} \frac{dN}{dt} & = & rN\left(1-\frac{N}{K}\right)-\alpha \frac{NP}{\beta P + \gamma N} \\
\frac{dP}{dt} & = & \epsilon \frac{NP}{\beta P + \gamma N} - \delta P \end{array}$$

with $N(t)$ the number of prey and $P(t)$ the number of predators.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 1) Google search ! There many sites on which you can find this interpretation 2) Why don't you type your equations (it takes at most 5 minutes) instead of giving an image

Comment: Hi Michael, for a better reception you have to include the equations, which can be typed using Latex language (you can Google it), between signs $\text{\$}$... as example, your equations are: $$ \begin{array}{r c l} \frac{dN}{dt} & = & rN\left(1-\frac{N}{K}\right)-\alpha \frac{NP}{\beta P + \gamma N} \\
\frac{dP}{dt} & = & \epsilon \frac{NP}{\beta P + \gamma N} - \delta P \end{array}$$
I have included it in your question this time, also you can use it to look in google since many academic equation are written in Latex language, just press "Edit" and take the equations text.

Comment: Can you tell us where you found these images from? Also, a brief note on your background in interpreting ODEs in general would be useful (not solving them).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each equation has two main terms on the right side, they can be interpreted as follows:

| species | term 1 | term 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $N$ | internal $N$ dynamic, typical logistic growth to carrying capacity $K$ | death due to predator $P$ encounters, scaled |
| $P$ | births increase with prey catches, scaled as above | death term |

The encounter term is scaled to be more realistic than the pure product $NP$. For $P\ll N$ it is mostly proportional to $P$, reflecting the fact that a predator just hunts as much as it can consume. In the exceptional situation that $N$ becomes very small, the encounters become proportional to $N$, which also seems a sensible behavior.